# Java Socket Programming Login as Anonymous on FTP

Tags: java, sockets, ftp

I'm a newbie in Java socket programming and right now, I have a hard time.

I would like to make a simple java program which can connect a socket in port 21, log as anonymous user, and put a password on it, so I can log as an anonymous in a proper way. I turn on my FTP on XAMPP, and run my application on eclipse. here the code :

```
public class ftpClient {
        Socket socket;
        PrintWriter pw;
        BufferedReader input;
        String info = "";
        public ftpClient(){
            try{
                socket = new Socket("localhost", 21);
                System.out.println("Masuk port 21");

                logUsername();

                sendPassword();
                closeEverything();
            }
            catch(IOException ioe){
                System.out.println("Kesalahan dalam Socket");
            }
        }

        public void logUsername()throws IOException{
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            pw.write("USER anonymous\n");
            pw.flush();
            System.out.println(input.readLine());
        }

        public void sendPassword()throws IOException{
            pw.write("PASS faris@gmail.com\n");
            pw.flush();
            System.out.println(input.readLine());
            System.out.println(input.readLine());
        }

        public void closeEverything() throws IOException{
            input.close();
            pw.close();
            socket.close();
        }
        public static void main(String[]args){
            new ftpClient();
            System.out.println("done");
        }
}
```

I was told that on FTP while log as anonymous you need enter an email address as a password, and here the output.

```
Masuk port 21
220 ProFTPD 1.3.3 Server (ProFTPD Default Installation) [127.0.0.1]
331 Password required for anonymous
530 Login incorrect.
done
```

Would you mind telling the wrong part? I'm sorry for my bad coding style. 
Thanks

Comment: Depends on the server you're connecting to. Are you sure it's configured to allow any password for anonymous access?

Comment: Oh really ? I'll check it first. I'm kinda new with this problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Promoted OP's comment to Answer:

Yes you are right. I haven't configure it yet. Thank you :)